# Nice URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: url, codeigniter

does anybody knows how i can get nice url`s in CodeIgniter like this: examplepage.com/sites/my-new-project instead of examplepage.com/sites/2

The last segment in the URI can be a title oder an other custom string.

Please help me ;)

Regards,

Peter

Comment: For an example, i have an controller and model to generate articles about products. There`s no helper to generate the links.

Comment: Why don't u form URL like that:

`site.com/controller/method/product_name`

controller:
`class Controller extends CI_Controller
{
  method($product_name = FALSE)
  { 
        generate article
  }
}`

e.g.: site.com/view/article/shoes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI's URLs are "nice" by default - you choose what they are.

Based on the idea of segments, CI has:

`controller/method/params`

So for instance:

```
class Article extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        // blah
    }

    function read($article=null)
    {
       // display article
    }
}
```

You can then produce links like:

`site.com/article/read/my-article-title`

`my-article-title` would be a URL slug stored in your database, which the `read` method will look up and return the appropriate content.

The other way as suggested is routing, but hey, the functionality is built right there so you may as well use it.

Comment: URLS in Codeigniter in an out-of-the-box default installation have index.php in them which is annoying and makes your URLs messy. Look up how to remove the index.php file from the URL as well for true clean URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use routing.php for this, to set up a custom route.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Good luck.